# Current Year in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to add Copyright @ 'current_year' to the footer (in cshtml file) of my page. I often made it using javascript but since I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 I would like to do this using ASP.

I was trying construction like:

```
@response.write("Current Year: "&Year(Date))
```

But it didn't work in MVC 3 and I can't find solution that is working.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Copyright @@ @DateTime.Now.Year
```

Comment: Shouldn't the @ be `&copy;`? As in, the Copyright symbol "©"?

Comment: You can just add '©', depends if your document is UTF-8.

Answer (score 4):

In a .razor page in an ASP.NET Core application, e.g. within the `<div> </div>` of your footer, the following works too:

```
Copyright &#169 @DateTime.Now.Year
```

*Added the copyright sign too and the double @@ is not needed in a razor page; it gives an error.*